# MySql Database Dump

Tags: php, mysql, backup

how to take the automatic Mysql database dump daily using PHP on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

you need to create a scheduled task in windows control panel, and pass it the mysqldump command

something like this

```
pathtomysql/mysqldump -h DB_HOST -u DB_USER -pDB_PASS db_name > local_filename
```

if you want to do that in php then you can as well
create a scheduled task in windows control panel, and pass it the path to your php script

something like this

```
pathtophp/php.exe pathtoscript/myscript.php
```

Keep in mind it probably wont use the same php.ini as the webserver, so your config might be different

you can all this to backup your database from php

```
system("/pathtomysql/mysqldump -h $host -u $user -p$pass $db_name > $tofilename 2>error.txt", $ret);
```

this also pipes the any error messages to error.txt
and you can read that file and email them to yourself if you feel the need